# Cómo configurar los limites de la vista googleMaps en un fragment, Android Studio?

Tags: android, google-maps

Buenos días, necesito ayuda con este tema, ya he podido mostrar un mapa con un marcador en la ubicación que requiero, pero me muestra todo el mapa completo de America, si alguien puede orientarme como puedo hacer para que solo muestre el area de interes o límitar la vista del mapa. a continuación el códijo e imagenes. muchas gracias.

Código Java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Retrieve the content view that renders the map.
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Get the SupportMapFragment and request notification
    // when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia,
    // and move the map's camera to the same location.
    LatLng bogota = new LatLng(4.653421, -74.145150);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(bogota)
            .title("Uniagustiniana"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(bogota));
}
```

Archivo xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.mapwithmarker.MapsMarkerActivity" />
```

Me genera la siguiente vista de mapa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo busco es mostrar la siguiente area:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: creo que esto te será de ayuda. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views?hl=es-419

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando la clase [CameraUpdateFactory](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory) puedes tener varias opciones por ejemplo definiendo ancho, alto y un padding:

[newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds bounds, int width, int height, int padding)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory.html#newLatLngBounds(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds,%20int,%20int,%20int))

otra opción, la más común, definiendo un nivel de zoom:

[newLatLngZoom(LatLng latLng, float zoom)](http://newLatLngZoom(LatLng%20latLng,%20float%20zoom))

Por ejemplo si necesitas aplicar un factor de zoom a tu mapa mediante la clase [CameraUpdateFactory](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory), se realizaría de esta forma:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia,
    // and move the map's camera to the same location.
    LatLng bogota = new LatLng(4.653421, -74.145150);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(bogota)
            .title("Uniagustiniana"));

   //googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(bogota));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(bogota, 14f));

}
```

con nivel de zoom `14f`, se desplegaría de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con nivel de zoom `16.1f`, se desplegaría de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

puedes ver todas las opciones en la [documentación oficial](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory).

Comment: Genial, muchisimas gracias

Comment: @Alfredo un placer amigo, saludos!.

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que hacer un acercamiento a la longitud/latitud del marker con `animateCamera`:

```
private void moverALocalizacion(LatLng localizacion)
{   
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(localizacion,15));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());

    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Lo unico que necesitas hacer para conseguir lo que quieres es modificar el parametro del metodo `moveCamera()` por `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng, float)`, `LatLng` son las coordenadas y `float` el nivel de zoom.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia,
    // and move the map's camera to the same location.
    LatLng bogota = new LatLng(4.653421, -74.145150);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(bogota)
            .title("Uniagustiniana"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(bogota, 10.1f));
}
```

> Juega con el nivel de zoom hasta que logres lo que quieres.

Comment: Muchas gracias.