# ¿Cómo mostrar la ubicación actual de un usuario en el mapa de otro usuario?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo dos mapas en mi aplicación, un mapa es para que el usuario (empleado) muestre su ubicación actual, el otro mapa es para que el otro usuario (dueño) pueda ver un marcador con la ubicación actual del primer usuario (el empleado).

Hasta el momento logro que el empleado muestre su ubicación actual en su mapa, y en el mapa del dueño veo el marcador del empleado pero sobre el ecuador, no con la latitud y longitud exacta del empleado.

```
//Clase MapaEmpleado
public class MapaEmpleado extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tvMensaje;
    TextView tvMensaje1;

    TextView txtEmailMD;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapa_empleado);

        tvMensaje = findViewById(R.id.tvMensaje);
        tvMensaje1  = findViewById(R.id.tvMensaje1);
        txtEmailMD = findViewById(R.id.txtEmailMD);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, 1000);

        } else {
            iniciarLocalizacion();
        }
    }

    public void iniciarLocalizacion() {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        LocalizacionEmpleado local = new LocalizacionEmpleado();

        local.setMapa(this, tvMensaje, tvMensaje1, txtEmailMD);

        final boolean gpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (!gpsEnabled) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, 1000);
            return;
        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, 0, local);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, 0, local);
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[]granResults) {
        if (requestCode == 1000) {
            if (granResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                iniciarLocalizacion();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}

//ClaseFragmentMapsEmpleado
public class FragmentMapsEmpleado extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    double latD, lonD;

    private Marker marker;

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    public FragmentMapsEmpleado() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle bundle) {
        View rootView = super.onCreateView(layoutInflater, viewGroup, bundle);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            this.latD = getArguments().getDouble("latD");
            this.lonD = getArguments().getDouble("lonD");
        }
        getMapAsync(this);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latD, lonD);

        float zoom = 17;

        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));

        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Empleado").snippet("Dirección").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));

        UiSettings settings = googleMap.getUiSettings();

        settings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    }

}

//Clase LocalizacionEmpleado
public class LocalizacionEmpleado extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    MapaDistribuidor mapaEmpleado;
    TextView tvMensaje;
    TextView tvMensaje1;
    TextView txtEmailMD;


    public MapaEmpleado getMapaEmpleado() {
        return mapaEmpleado;
    }

    public void setMapa(MapaEmpleado mapaEmpleado, TextView tvMensaje, TextView tvMensaje1, TextView txtEmailMD) {
        this.mapaEmpleado = mapaEmpleado;
        this.tvMensaje = tvMensaje;
        this.tvMensaje1 = tvMensaje1;
        this.txtEmailMD = txtEmailMD;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        String texto = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        String texto1 = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

        tvMensaje.setText(texto);
        tvMensaje1.setText(texto1);

        mapaEmpleado(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        LocalizacionDueño local = new LocalizacionDueño();
        local.mapaDueño(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    }

    public void mapaEmpleado(double latD, double lonD) {
        FragmentMapsEmpleado fragment = new FragmentMapsEmpleado();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putDouble("latD", new Double(latD));
        bundle.putDouble("lonD", new Double(lonD));
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getMapaEmpleado().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentEmpleado, fragment, null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        switch (status) {
            case LocationProvider
                    .AVAILABLE:
                Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.AVAILABLE");
                break;
            case LocationProvider
                    .OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE");
                break;
            case LocationProvider
                    .TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        tvMensaje.setText("GPS Activado");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        tvMensaje.setText("GPS Desactivado");
    }

}

//ClaseMapaDueño
public class MapaDueño extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView localizacionDueño;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapa_dueño);

        localizacionDueño = findViewById(R.id.localizacionDueño);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, 1000);

        } else {
            iniciarLocalizacionDueño();
        }
    }

    private void iniciarLocalizacionDueño() {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        LocalizacionDueño local = new LocalizacionDueño();

        local.setMapaDueño(this, localizacionDueño);

        final boolean gpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (!gpsEnabled) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, 1000);
            return;
        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, 0, local);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, 0, local);

        localizacionDueño.setText("Localización agregada");
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[]granResults) {
        if (requestCode == 1000) {
            if (granResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                iniciarLocalizacionDueño();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}

//Clase FragmentMapsDueño
public class FragmentMapsDueño extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    double lat, lon;

    private GoogleMap map;

    public FragmentMapsDueño() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle bundle) {
        View rootView = super.onCreateView(layoutInflater, viewGroup, bundle);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            this.lat = getArguments().getDouble("lat");
            this.lon = getArguments().getDouble("lon");
        }
        getMapAsync(this);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        map = googleMap;

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lon);

        float zoom = 17;

        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));

        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Entregar aquí").draggable(true));

        UiSettings settings = map.getUiSettings();

        settings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    }

}

//Clase LocalizacionDueño
public class LocalizacionDueño implements LocationListener {

    MapaDueño mapaDueño;
    TextView localizacionDueño;

    public MapaDueño getMapaDueño() {
        return mapaDueño;
    }

    public void setMapaDueño(MapaDueño mapaDueño, TextView localizacionDueño) {
        this.mapaDueño = mapaDueño;
        this.localizacionDueño = localizacionDueño;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        String texto = "Mi ubicación es Dueño: \n" + "Latitud = " + location.getLatitude() + "\n" + "Longitud = " + location.getLongitude();

        localizacionDueño.setText(texto);
    }

    public void mapaDueño(double latD, double lonD) {
        FragmentMapsDueño fragment = new FragmentMapsDueño();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putDouble("latD", new Double(latD));
        bundle.putDouble("lonD", new Double(lonD));
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getMapaDueño().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment, fragment, null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        switch (status) {
            case LocationProvider
                    .AVAILABLE:
                Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.AVAILABLE");
                break;
            case LocationProvider
                    .OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE");
                break;
            case LocationProvider
                    .TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        localizacionConsumidor.setText("GPS Activado");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        localizacionConsumidor.setText("GPS Desactivado");
    }
    
}
```

Tal vez algo me falta pero aún estoy aprendiendo lo de las localizaciones en android studio.

***//Edito la pregunta para agregar las siguientes líneas:***
Al momento de abrir el mapa del usuario (empleado) me marca el siguiente error:

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager com.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.iu.managedbean.MapaDueño.getSupportFragmentManager()' on a null object reference

El error hace referencia a la línea del mapa del usuario (dueño), pero el mapa del dueño lo puedo abrir normal.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getMapaDueño().getSupportFragmentManager(); //Linea donde marca el error
```

Comment: Hola kayvos, imprime que valores de zoom, latitud, longitud obtiene el usuario, eso debe ser el problema, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que el problema en el mapa del usuario se ve de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso lo que debes de realizar es que en la app del usuario asegures [mover a la posición y con un zoom aceptable la cámara en el mapa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/96620/95) como lo realizas aquí:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {    
    mMap = googleMap;    
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latD, lonD);    
    float zoom = 17;    
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));    
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);    
    marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Empleado").snippet("Dirección").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));    
    UiSettings settings = googleMap.getUiSettings();    
    settings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
}
```

Si continuas viendo el marcador sobre el ecuador, debes asegurar un nivel de zoom adecuado y valores correctos para latitud y longitud.

Comment: Gracias por responder Jorgesys♦. Ya he configurado lo del zoom y me he dado cuenta que me marca en 0.0 la latitud y la longitud. También me di cuenta que al abrir el mapa del usuario (empleado) me marca un error y no lo puedo ver. Editaré la pregunta para agregar el error.

Comment: Si @Kayvos, la geolocalización 0,0 es la razón por la cual vez en el ecuador el marcador. Claro recuerda revisar el LogCat.

Comment: Jorgesys♦  crees que la latitud y longitud la marque en 0.0 porque el mapa del empleado no lo puedo abrir, por el error que marca.

Comment: El error "getSupportFragmentManager()' on a null object reference" es un problema diferente, debes usar la activity que contiene el Fragment como contexto, por ejemplo: getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()